# how can I find out the configuration of a cassandra cluster created using ccm

Tags: ccm

I have created two clusters locally using ccm.

```
 .\ccm.py create test -v 3.11.1
 .\ccm.py create test2 -v 2.1.2
```

I can list the different clusters using `list` argument in `ccm` but I am unable to find out which argument I should use to check which version of `cassardra` a cluster is using. Is there any such argument which I can pass to `ccm`?

I notice that `ccm` creates a `cluster.conf` file for each cluster which has the information about the version of `cassandra` the cluster uses but I am wondering if there is a `cli` command as well.